# What's the meaning of all indexes in a single treatment?

Tags: r, lsmeans, glmm

For the first time, a GLMM model has strange behaviour in the marginal means. I find:

```
lsm.mTGCp.temp <- lsmeans(mTGCp, c("temperatura"), type="response")
cld(lsm.mTGCp.temp, Letters=letters, decreasing = TRUE)
```

[image: printscreen]

What's the meaning of `abcdef`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "What's the meaning of abcdef?" Umm, treatments that don't share a letter are significantly different.